# Check if a value is part of a list, the name of the list being in a variable

Tags: ansible

I try to find if a variable has a valid value which is stored in a list.
The name of the list is also stored in a variable. If the variable is not valid the test should fail.
This works if I use the name of the list:

```yaml
- fail: msg="unsupported version requested"
  when: requestedversion not in windowsversionlist
```

But the name of the `versionlist` is also a variable because there are more lists like linux and windows.

This does not work:

```yaml
- fail: msg="unsupported version requested"
  when: requesterversion not in versionlist
```

The value of the variable `versionlist` is `windowsversionlist`

I try `{{ versionlist }}`, etc. but this does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html):

```yaml
- fail: 
    msg: "unsupported version requested"
  when: "requestedversion not in lookup('vars', versionlist)"
```

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - fail: 
        msg: "unsupported version requested"
      when: "requestedversion not in lookup('vars', versionlist)"
      vars:
        requestedversion: a.a.a
        versionlist: windowsversionlist
        windowsversionlist: 
          - x.x.x
          - y.y.y
          - z.z.z
```

This gives:

```
TASK [fail] *******************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: unsupported version requested
```